# in keycloak is it possible to use alternative authentication flow as URL parameter

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect

The default "Browser" flow which is binded to "Browser Flow" (in the "Bindings" tab) should force the login through a SAML IDP.

We also need the ability to use the login-form, so I was thinking to copy the default "Browser" flow and activate the login-form and create a custom URL which uses the new authentication flow. I didn't find any documentation that specifies such a parameter.

I know it is possible to bind the new flow to a client, but the client that we have needs to login through SAML so I can't bind the "login-flow" to the client.

Is there a parameter for defining the authentication flow?
Any alternative to achieve this scenario (default force SAML, alternative login-form)?

Answer (score 1):

The OpenID Connect standard solution is to send an `acr_values` query parameter from the client application. Looks like better support for that flow is [coming soon in Keycloak 17](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/pull/7897).

In the meantime, I believe one workaround is to set this value when configuring a second authorize URL, as [suggested here](https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/how-to-set-acr-values-with-external-identity-provider/6723/2), though it imakes the selection more difficult for client apps:

```
/authorize?acr_values=myid
```

Comment: The issue https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-847 looks very promising. Will test this as soon as Keycloak 17 is released. The "Flow logic example" in the documentation should cover my use-case: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-community/blob/main/design/multi-factor-admin-and-step-up.md